# Quel pronom utiliser avec le verbe "apporter" ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, compléments

Je suis désolé pour mon français. J'apprends encore ! Si je veux dire «Je veux apporter ma chienne» avec un pronom objet, est-ce que je dirais «Je veux l'apporter» ou «Je veux lui apporter»? C'est elle que je veux apporter, je ne lui apporte pas quelque-chose.

Answer (score 2):

Ton français est très bon, et surtout compréhensible, aucun problème.

Il y a une différence entre:

- > Je lui apporte.

Ici, le "lui" représente quelque chose que tu apportes **à** ta chienne. (C'est un *complément d'objet indirect* (COI), ou si tu préfères, c'est le *datif* en latin)

Par exemple:

*J'apporte des croquettes **à** ma chienne*: Je *lui* apporte. (à ma chienne)
Ou: *Je lui apporte des croquettes*.

Je dis **à** Gaston qu'il faut qu'il prenne son courrier: Je *lui* dis. (à Gaston)
Ou: *Je lui dis qu'il faut prendre son courrier*.

En classe, on nous avait appris à poser **cette question** pour reconnaître le COI/datif:

**À qui (/À quoi) c'est apporté**? (ou autre verbe). Ici: À qui les croquettes sont apportées?

- Et:

> Je l'apporte.

Ici, c'est *la chienne* qui est l'objet, c'est *elle* qui est apportée.

C'est un *complément d'objet direct* (COD), équivalent à l'*accusatif* du latin.
On remarque qu'il s'appelle *direct*, parce qu'il y a *directement* verbe+complément, et pas de préposition au milieu, comme le "à" de tout à l'heure (qui était donc *indirect*).

En classe, enfants, on nous a appris à poser **cette question**, pour savoir s'il s'agit d'un COD:

**Qu'est-ce (/qui est-ce) qui est apporté**? (ou autre verbe)

**NB**: J'ai édité ton titre, car il n'y a pas de pronoms indirects ou directs.

Comment: Pour *Je veux lui apporter*, il y a une autre façon de comprendre *lui* : *je veux apporter ma chienne au vétérinaire*.

Comment: Ici l'usage correct serait: Amener ma chienne au vétérinaire. Je lui amène ma chienne = "lui" étant vétérinaire.

Comment: Tout comme dans ton exemple de *je l'apporte* qui devrait plutôt être *je l'amène*. Ce que je voulais dire c'est que dans *je lui apporte*, *lui* ne désigne pas forcément la chienne à laquelle on apporte quelque chose mais peut désigner une tierce personne à qui on apporte la chienne (auquel cas la chienne est l'objet).

Comment: ça dépend vraiment du contexte. on pourrait dire "J'apporte mon chien avec moi" (en voyage). Tu as raison, ça peut être une tierce personne, mais ici, dans l'exemple que j'ai pris, j'avais pris l'exemple des croquettes. Je lui apporte. (l'objet apporté est: croquette, et la destinataire ("lui"): la chienne, mais si l'objet apporté est la chienne, et la destinataire: ma tante("lui), ça revient au même. C'est pour ça que j'ai précisé la phrase entière que "Je lui apporte" est censé raccourcir, car tu peux trouver d'autres exemples.

Comment: On peut aussi parachever la construction en combinant les deux pronoms : "J'ai acheté une balle pour la chienne, va la lui apporter"

Answer (score 2):

Même si « apporter » et « amener » sont de plus en plus utilisés l'un pour l'autre, « apporter » est normalement utilisé pour des objets alors qu'« amener/emmener » est utilisé pour des choses animées (qu'on n'a en général pas besoin de porter). Il est donc mieux de dire :

> J'amène ma chienne chez le vétérinaire.
>
> Je l'amène chez le vétérinaire. (qui/quoi ? ma chienne: complément d'objet direct défini => le, la, les)
>
> J'y amène ma chienne. (où ? chez le vétérinaire: complément de lieu => y)
>
> Je l'y amène.

Pour contre, on dira bien :

> J'apporte des croquettes à ma chienne.
>
> Je lui apporte des croquettes. (À qui ? à ma chienne: complément d'objet indirect avec une personne/une chose animée => lui (singulier) ou leur (pluriel))
>
> J'en apporte à ma chienne. (Quoi ? des croquettes: complément d'objet direct exprimant une quantité => en)
>
> Je lui en apporte.

Le choix du pronom ne dépend pas directement du verbe utilisé mais du type de complément qu'il remplace.

Comme signalé par @GAM PUB, les verbes transitifs, directs ou indirects, impliquent l'usage d'un type de complément particulier. Apporter, par exemple, est transitif direct, ce qui fait que le complément d'objet n'a pas de préposition.

Comment: Pour la conclusion, on pourrait dire que le choix du pronom dépend indirectement du verbe puisque le type des compléments est lié aux propriétés de celui-ci ([sous-catégorisation](https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Module_lexical#La_sous-cat.C3.A9gorisation)).

Answer (score 0):

> Je veux l'apporter

Est la bonne réponse.

Correction :

> Elle est le chose
>
> > Elle est **la** chose